# PyQt4: qDrawShadeLine: Invalid parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt4

I've created a ui using QtDesigner and load .ui files in the init method like this

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(DataGrabberApp, self).__init__(parent)
    uic.loadUi('mainWindow.ui', self)
    self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
    self.show()
```

On load and when I resize the application the error qDrawShadeLine: Invalid parameters is thrown in the console and the application runs as usual. I am not sure how to explain this any further, this is my first PyQt4 project. I guess PyQt catches the error somewhere, but not sure where because I never use qDrawShadeLine in my code. The only other think I can think about to add is probably the ui file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="enabled">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>675</width>
    <height>689</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="autoFillBackground">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="documentMode">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="dockNestingEnabled">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_9">
    <item>
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
      <item>
       <widget class="QGroupBox" name="gbIP_2">
        <property name="title">
         <string>Report Selection</string>
        </property>
        <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_7">
         <item>
          <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
           <item row="0" column="4">
            <widget class="QLabel" name="lblTS2">
             <property name="text">
              <string>Reports per test</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="0" column="1">
            <widget class="QDateEdit" name="deStartTS">
             <property name="maximumSize">
              <size>
               <width>97</width>
               <height>22</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="dateTime">
              <datetime>
               <hour>0</hour>
               <minute>0</minute>
               <second>0</second>
               <year>2017</year>
               <month>1</month>
               <day>1</day>
              </datetime>
             </property>
             <property name="displayFormat">
              <string>dd/MM/yyyy</string>
             </property>
             <property name="calendarPopup">
              <bool>true</bool>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="0" column="2">
            <widget class="QLabel" name="lblTS1">
             <property name="frameShape">
              <enum>QFrame::HLine</enum>
             </property>
             <property name="frameShadow">
              <enum>QFrame::Sunken</enum>
             </property>
             <property name="lineWidth">
              <number>-1</number>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string>End:</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="0" column="3">
            <widget class="QDateEdit" name="deEndTS">
             <property name="maximumSize">
              <size>
               <width>97</width>
               <height>22</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="autoFillBackground">
              <bool>true</bool>
             </property>
             <property name="dateTime">
              <datetime>
               <hour>0</hour>
               <minute>0</minute>
               <second>0</second>
               <year>2017</year>
               <month>1</month>
               <day>1</day>
              </datetime>
             </property>
             <property name="displayFormat">
              <string>dd/MM/yyyy</string>
             </property>
             <property name="calendarPopup">
              <bool>true</bool>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="1" column="0">
            <widget class="QRadioButton" name="rbLastHours">
             <property name="text">
              <string>Last hours: </string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="0" column="0">
            <widget class="QRadioButton" name="rbStart">
             <property name="text">
              <string>Time Stamp:</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="2" column="0">
            <widget class="QRadioButton" name="rbLastReports">
             <property name="text">
              <string>Last reports per test:</string>
             </property>
             <property name="checked">
              <bool>true</bool>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="0" column="5">
            <widget class="QSpinBox" name="sbReportsTS">
             <property name="maximumSize">
              <size>
               <width>34</width>
               <height>22</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="wrapping">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
             <property name="maximum">
              <number>50</number>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="1" column="1">
            <widget class="QSpinBox" name="sbHours">
             <property name="maximumSize">
              <size>
               <width>36</width>
               <height>22</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="maximum">
              <number>500</number>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="2" column="1">
            <widget class="QSpinBox" name="sbReports">
             <property name="maximumSize">
              <size>
               <width>36</width>
               <height>22</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="maximum">
              <number>50</number>
             </property>
             <property name="value">
              <number>5</number>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QComboBox" name="cbSets"/>
    </item>
    <item>
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
      <item>
       <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabReport">
        <property name="enabled">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="contextMenuPolicy">
         <enum>Qt::DefaultContextMenu</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="tabShape">
         <enum>QTabWidget::Rounded</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="currentIndex">
         <number>3</number>
        </property>
        <property name="iconSize">
         <size>
          <width>20</width>
          <height>20</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="tabsClosable">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="movable">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
        <widget class="QWidget" name="tab">
         <attribute name="title">
          <string>Log Files</string>
         </attribute>
         <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_5">
          <item>
           <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_4">
            <item>
             <widget class="QTreeView" name="tvTests">
              <property name="minimumSize">
               <size>
                <width>256</width>
                <height>367</height>
               </size>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_8">
              <item>
               <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnAddAllLogFiles">
                <property name="text">
                 <string>Add All</string>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item>
               <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnClearAllLogFiles">
                <property name="text">
                 <string>Clear</string>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
             </layout>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QTreeView" name="tvSelected">
              <property name="minimumSize">
               <size>
                <width>256</width>
                <height>367</height>
               </size>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_2">
         <attribute name="title">
          <string>Raw Data</string>
         </attribute>
         <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_8">
          <item>
           <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_7">
            <item>
             <widget class="QTreeView" name="tvRawData">
              <property name="minimumSize">
               <size>
                <width>256</width>
                <height>367</height>
               </size>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
              <item>
               <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnAddAllRawData">
                <property name="text">
                 <string>Add All</string>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item>
               <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnClearAllRawData">
                <property name="text">
                 <string>Clear</string>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
             </layout>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QTreeView" name="tvSelectedRawData">
              <property name="minimumSize">
               <size>
                <width>256</width>
                <height>367</height>
               </size>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_3">
         <attribute name="title">
          <string>MCs</string>
         </attribute>
         <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_6">
          <item>
           <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
            <item>
             <widget class="QTreeView" name="tvMCs">
              <property name="minimumSize">
               <size>
                <width>256</width>
                <height>367</height>
               </size>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_4">
              <item>
               <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnAddAllMCs">
                <property name="text">
                 <string>Add All</string>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item>
               <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnClearMCs">
                <property name="text">
                 <string>Clear</string>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
             </layout>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QTreeView" name="tvSelectedMCs">
              <property name="minimumSize">
               <size>
                <width>256</width>
                <height>367</height>
               </size>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_4">
         <attribute name="title">
          <string>Scenarios</string>
         </attribute>
         <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_6">
          <item>
           <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
            <item>
             <widget class="QTreeView" name="tvApplications">
              <property name="minimumSize">
               <size>
                <width>256</width>
                <height>367</height>
               </size>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_5">
              <item>
               <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnAddAllApplications">
                <property name="text">
                 <string>Add All</string>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item>
               <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnClearApplications">
                <property name="text">
                 <string>Clear</string>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
             </layout>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QTreeView" name="tvSelectedApplications">
              <property name="minimumSize">
               <size>
                <width>256</width>
                <height>367</height>
               </size>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
    <item>
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnSaveAs">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Save As</string>
        </property>
        <property name="autoDefault">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnSave">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Save Paths</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnStart">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Start</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnLoadFrom">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Load From</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnLoad">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Load Paths</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>675</width>
     <height>26</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```